# Meteor update isopacket giving `combined` error - sourcemapConsumer.destroy is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Every time I try to update a project or create a project with 1.9 and above in Meteor I get the following error:

```
Errors prevented isopacket load:

While loading isopacket `combined`:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.9.2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\fs\tools\fs\files.ts:1170:25: sourcemapConsumer.destroy is not a function
...
```

Don't know why this error keeps showing up. I have already uninstalled and reinstalled Meteor.

The error is `sourcemapConsumer.destroy is not a function`

I can use `meteor create` and `meteor run` with versions 1.8.3 and below. My old programs still run. Sometimes with meteor 1.9 it will create a project while still providing the error and if I try to run the code I get the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not a perfect solution, what helped me out to get to version 1.10.2 was modifying files.js and linker.js. I have suggested how meteor repo may be fixed and how I got it running on my Windows 10 64-bit machine in this answer:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10930#issuecomment-630721277

I hope my hacky method helps anyone struggling. If there is a better solution please mention it so others can also benefit.

Hope this helps!